# VMExtensionProvisioningError :while creating TeamServicesAgent extension on azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

```
params = self.compute_client.models().VirtualMachineExtension(location="southeastasia",
                     publisher='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services',
                     virtual_machine_extension_type='TeamServicesAgent',
                     type_handler_version='1.14',
                     auto_upgrade_minor_version=True,
                     settings={
                       "vstsAccountName": "xyz",
                       "teamProject": "xyz",
                       "deploymentGroup": "Virtual Machine Test",
                       "agentName": "",
                       "tags": ""
                     },
                     protected_settings={
                     "PATToken": "uy4luslycpkjhXXXXXXXnypzcnrlfXXXuddxrXXXXwdw5hxbzlxv5ja"   
                     }
)
```

I'm getting an error like `Message: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'hello'. Error message: "Failed to get status file [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TeamServicesAgent-1.14.0.0/status/0.status'".`

Is there any wrong parameter in settings property?

Comment: are you sure you are using the latest extensión versión. also which vm image are you using?

Comment: @4c74356b41 yes, I'm using the latest version and I'm deploying on Ubuntu 16.04-LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `virtual_machine_extension_type='TeamServicesAgent'`  only works for Windows VM. For linux VM, you should use `TeamServicesAgentLinux`.

You could see this [link](https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20161101/microsoft.vsts-agent-linux-arm.1.0.0/Artifacts/MainTemplate.json).